# Using Firestore data inside Angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have an interface

```
interface Profile {
    finishedTutorial: boolean,
    displayName: string,
    spellCollection: number[]
}
```

and variables for document/observable

```
profileDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Profile>;
profile: Observable<Profile>;
```

and then I assign these variables

```
this.profileDoc = this.afs.doc('profiles/' + authService.userId);
this.profile = this.profileDoc.valueChanges();
```

I can use it in HTML without any major problems

```
<div class="profile" *ngIf="profile | async as p">
    <h1>{{ p.displayName }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ p.finishedTutorial }}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let s of p.spellCollection">{{ s }}</li>
    </ul>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <input type="text" name="displayName" [ngModel]="p.displayName">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="authService.userId == null">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My problem is that I need that `spellCollection` array inside my typescript file, because I want to use it as a query for other collection/document. I really can't figure how to use that there. Found couple of solutions with using `.map` but i don't know what's happening since I don't think I can use `.map` with `.doc`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use `.subscribe` on the `profile: Observable<Profile>;` observable in your TS file. Then when a value is emitted as part of `spellCollection` array you can assign it to any variable in your TS file. `.subscribe` is part of Rxjs Observables which should be present in your existing ts page

Comment: for example below collection `const collection$: Observable<Item> = collection.valueChanges()
collection$.subscribe(data => console.log(data) )`

Comment: check this link : https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-with-angularfire-basics/

Comment: Yes, this helped me for now. Thank you :)

Comment: you are welcome , i just posted this as suggestion not an answer i think you can take it further from here